# English equivalent of the French "trompe-oreilles"?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, ambiguity

The following is the translation of the French definition of **trompe-oreilles** as it appears on the Wikipedia page:

> A [*trompe-oreilles*](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trompe-oreilles) is a valid sentence that, when spoken out loud, gives the impression of being in a foreign language or having a different meaning.

Is there a similar concept in English? (Any examples?)

A rough example: "I fly to you" could be misinterpreted as "I've lied to you".

Comment: [Mondegreen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen)

Comment: Did you look up *trompe-oreilles* in a bilingual dictionary?

Comment: Yes, it wasn't in my Collins. And Google Translate gave me "horn earrings" which isn't the sense I'm after. I wondered if *ear-twister* might be a candidate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Oronym** — [About.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/mo/g/oronymterm.htm)

> A sequence of words (for example, "ice cream") that sounds the same as a different sequence of words ("I scream").
>
> The term oronym was coined by Gyles Brandreth in The Joy of Lex (1980).

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oronym)

> *noun* 1. A word or phrase that sounds the same as another word or phrase.

From ["Oronyms and Homophones"](http://www.fun-with-words.com/nym_oronyms.html) by Fun With Words,

> Oronyms (or **homophones**) are words which sound the same.
>
> Generally the word homophone is used to describe one of a pair or group of words that have the same sound (like *prince* and *prints*; *allowed* and *aloud*), whilst oronyms are normally strings of words (phrases) such as *iced ink* and *I stink*

**Eggcorn** — [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eggcorn)

> In linguistics, an eggcorn is an idiosyncratic substitution of a word or phrase for a word or words that sound similar or identical in the speaker's dialect (sometimes called **oronyms**). The new phrase introduces a meaning that is different from the original, but plausible in the same context, such as "old-timers' disease" for "Alzheimer's disease".

See also: [Mondegreen](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mondegreen), from a comment by James McLeod